# Re-start VM Instance after stop (for changing the machine type)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines

I would like to change the machine type in VM instance so I stop the VM instance and change it and edit it. However, I cannot restart it afterwards and the message below is shown:

a g1-small vm instance is currently unavailable in the asia-southeast1-a zone. alternatively, you can try your request again with a different vm hardware configuration or at a later time. for more information, see the troubleshooting documentation.

Would be pleased if anyone could advise how could I fix the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt launching the VM instance on a different type of computer. You might be able to launch the instance using a different machine type that is available in the same zone if the g1-small machine type isn't available. Start the VM instance in a different zone, if possible. You might be able to start the instance in a different zone where the g1-small machine type is available if the asia-southeast1-a zone does not have it.